# How to insert the result of for loop to one array in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, for-loop

I have this script

```
for row in c:
    res = subprocess.Popen('bgpq3 -4 {} -m 24 -l {}'.format(row[5],row[2]), shell=True, universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = res.communicate()
    for line in stdout.split('\n')[1:10]:
          print(line)
```

which results:

```
ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.6.0/23
ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.8.0/24
ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.9.0/24
ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.10.0/24
```

how can i put these lists to one array?
something like this or a better way that will be easier!

```
{ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.10.0/24,ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.8.0/24,ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.9.0/24,ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.10.0/24}
```

And also how can i query them at the next time? like the reverse way to get multiple rows!

I used this but get multiple rows with multiple arrays

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO newpeers (prefix) VALUES(ARRAY['{}'])ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING".format(line))
```

i have also tried to append the result to a list but i am getting more than one list

```
lines = []
for line in stdout.split('\n')[1:10]:
```

Comment: Don't use string formatting to build queries for results, it's an SQL injection risk; look into parameterized queries. Just append the result to a list (you're using `set` syntax) and use `executemany`

Comment: Appending the result to a list will results is more than one list in this case.

Comment: That's the point of `executemany`. It's as though you had an `execute` command in a `for` loop.